# Expression of the Runge function's derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to get the nth derivative of the Runge function i.e. i want :
$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \dfrac{1}{1+25x^2}.$$

Mathematica gives me the answer : 
$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \dfrac{1}{1+25x^2}=\dfrac{n! (-50 x)^n }{(1+25x^2)^{n+1}}  {_2F_1}\left(\dfrac{1-n}{2},-\dfrac{n}{2};-n; 1 + \dfrac{1}{25x^2} \right).$$

I don't know how to get Mathematica's result, could you give me some clue ?

Comment: Hint: It is a bit easier to take the derivatives of $\frac{1}{1+5ix}$ and $\frac{1}{1-5ix}$.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the fraction into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and simplify the expression. Then, by way of induction, find a general formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of its general term, and rewrite it using the definition of the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) $_{_2}F_{_1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found : $\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \dfrac{1}{1+25x^2} = (-50 x)^n \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty (-1)^k (-k)_n \left(25x^2\right)^{k-n}$. Is it correct ?

Comment: @Joelafrite: Apparently not. However, your mistakes are trivial. My advice? After writing the series for $\dfrac1{1+25x^2}$, separate *x* from its coefficients. It will make life much easier. ;-)